# Wordpress shortcode button does not center align. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: wordpress, button, paypal, alignment, shortcode

This is my website: www.richardsearsmusic.com. How come this button won't center align?

[wp_cart_button name="Skyline pre-order" price="$15"]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the relevant code code to your problem, and also tell us what you have tried to make it work.

Comment: hi, thanks: <p style="text-align: center;">[wp_cart_button name="Skyline pre-order" price="$15"]</p>

Comment: You button is being otput outside of this p, into div with class `wp_cart_button_wrapper` which got `text-align:left`

Comment: thanks, and what would i change or add specifically to fix that?

Comment: actually that made sense - thanks! got it!

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use CSS for this button ? If it didn't worked then i suggest you to use something like this.

```html
<div class="align-button">[wp_cart_button name="Skyline pre-order" price="$15"] </div> 
   
   .align-button { text-align: center; }
```

Either you can use float or margin/left/right to make it centre.